# How often was the -i- stem dropped in second declension nouns?

Tags: morphology

In chapter four of Wheelock's Latin, it states that:

> In spelling the genitive singular of neuter (and masculine) nouns with a base ending in -i- the Romans sometimes dropped that vowel, e.g., cōnsilī for cōnsiliī (see above) and fīlī for fīliī; in this book, however, the stem vowel is regularly retained.

How often is *often*? Did this happen only with select words of this declension or was it pervasive? Is this something that became more common over time as Latin evolved or was it distinct to a specific period or location?

Comment: Related: [Forms of 2nd Declension Neuter Nouns ending in -ium](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2007). Side note: in Indo-European comparative etymology, second-declension nouns ending in *-ius* and *-ium* are categorized as o-stems and considered to have stems ending in *-io-* (whereas *i*-stem nouns are nouns in the third declension that take endings like *-ium* in the genitive plural or *-ia* in the neuter nominative/accusative plural).